# AppEngine SDK 1.8.7 failed to install in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to work with Google App Engine. I have Eclipse Juno on my MacBook (Mountain Lion), and I have upgraded my Java to 1.7.0_45. I tried following instructions as per Google on its Developers link to add the Google SDK to my Eclipse. When I open my preferences in Eclipse, it shows: Failed to initialize App Engine SDK 1.8.7

How do I resolve this issue? What is it that I am doing wrong or have missed doing??

I have tried to break my head on this and even tried to search for solutions but did not find any!
Help!

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace generated in the eclipse logs?

Comment: Although it seems that you are using Java, but which SDK language that you downloaded: PHP / Java / Phyton / Go ?

Comment: I havent run the project in eclipse. It simply is an error on the project which I am trying to resolve through the preferences.

Comment: I have downloaded the Java SDK for GAE

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/DevAppServerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself, and after installing Java 7 JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/, I followed the steps bellow and the "Failed to initialize..." error disappeared:

1. Under Eclipse / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs, click
   Add, select Mac OS X VM, then click Next.
2. Enter "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home" as the
   JRE home directory, as well as a JRE name, click Finish.
3. Check the box next to the new JRE that you just added and then click OK.
4. Under Eclipse / Preferences / Java / Compiler, select 1.7 from the "Compiler compliance level" drop-down list and click Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling AppEngine SDK 1.8.7 from Eclipse.  Here is a more detailed [installation guide](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2) for the Google Plugin for Eclipse on the Juno (3.8/4.2) version.  You need to select the Google Plugin for Eclipse and the SDK for AppEngine as a minimum.  Currently you will get AppEngine SDK 1.8.9.  Good luck!

If that fails try with a newer Eclipse (4.3 Kepler).